# How can I pass the name of a $scope variable to watch by putting an = after my directive name?

Tags: angularjs

I call a directive like this:

```
<textarea class="pagedown-admin"
   data-modal="modal"
   data-pagedown-admin
   ng:model="modal.data.text"
   data-pid="modal.data.questionId"></textarea>
```

Inside the directive I have this:

```
 return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            modal: '=modal',
            ngModel: '=',
            pid: '=pid'
        },
,
        template: '<div class="pagedown-bootstrap-editor"></div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

            scope.$watch('pid', function (newValue, oldValue) {
                    //console.log("newValue: " + newValue);
                    //console.log("oldValue: " + oldValue);
                    var val = ngModel.$modelValue;
                    //console.log(val)
                    if (val !== undefined) {
                        $wmdInput.val(val);
                        editor.refreshPreview();
                    }
                });
```

Is there a simple way that I could change this so that my directive call looks like:

```
<textarea class="pagedown-admin"
   data-modal="modal"
   data-pagedown-admin="modal.data.questionId"
   ng:model="modal.data.text"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just refer to the normalised form of the directive name in the scope object, just like any other attribute. So

```
scope: {
  modal: '=modal',
  ngModel: '=',
  pid: '=pid'
}
```

can be changed to

```
scope: {
  modal: '=modal',
  ngModel: '=',
  pageDownAdmin: '='
}
```

Then the watcher can use `pageDownAdmin` instead of `pid`:

```
scope.$watch('pageDownAdmin', function (newValue, oldValue) {...});
```

Also, it is more usual to be consistent with the format you use for directives. You seem to use both the 'ng:' and 'data-' prefixed formats, which seems a bit confusing.